# Transforming Part Of R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, transform

I wish to transform part of a dataframe to take on of the columns values and append it to the column names. An example of what I have is shown below:

```
dates <- c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02")
gender <- c("Male","Male","Female")
Age <- c("Eighteen","NineTeen","Twenty")
Count <- c(1,2,1)

Data <- data.frame(dates,gender,Age,Count)
```

Output:

[image]

Desired Example DF:

```
dates <- c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-02")
gender <- c("Male","Male","Female")
Eighteen <- c(1,0,0)
Nineteen <- c(0,2,0)
Twenty <- c(0,0,1)

Data2 <- data.frame(dates,gender,Eighteen,Nineteen,Twenty)
```

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(Data, names_from = Age, values_from = Count, values_fill = list(Count = 0))`

Comment: `dcast(as.data.table(Data), dates + gender ~ Age, value.var = "Count", fill = 0)` (using the `data.table` package)